# Is rust a good thermal insulator as opposed to bare steel or hardened clay?

Tags: thermodynamics, physical-chemistry, thermal-conductivity, metals

I have no idea, if this is the correct site to find an answer on this topic, but considering it's a question of physical interactions I wanna give it a shot. I am in no way a physicist, just a hobbyist trying to find the perfect material for his forge so nothing gets too heated. If anyone would mind doing a bit of a bonus, how would I account for clay's heat expansion, if I do decide to go that route?

Comment: You might want to look at a table of thermal conductivities, such as this one here: https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/thermal-conductivity-d_429.html; lower numbers are better insulators.

Comment: @probably_someone I didn't know a table like that existed, thank you so much

Comment: There must be a lot of articles on forge making?

Comment: @probably_someone the problem with that table is that forges heat up towards 1200 C, so those numbers in the table are rather useless b/c they're for room-temperature. That said, I wouldn't be surprised if a similar table existed for such high temperature environment.

Comment: Scale on heat exchangers is a real problem in, say, power plants.

Comment: Do you mean for a furnace heating steel to be forged? Rust is unstable at any high temperature, so there is no answer. Iron oxides are poor thermal insulators.  Fire brick over fiber insulation would be  good.

Answer (score 0):

Not to worry about rust as an insulator. In a forge, the thickness of an oxide layer on the outside of the vessel is tiny compared to the dimensions of the forge itself, and any change in heat transfer because of it will be too small to measure. Agree with Physics Dave; there should be a lot of on-line resources that can help.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to attach a wire to a rusted rod, you would have attached enough area of the wire to get contact on the metal core. This is because most of the rust falls off. So only a thin layer of (weakly bonded) rust is found on the surface of the rod. So for practical purposes, a rusted iron rod and a bare iron rod work almost the same.
Pure rust is oxidised form of iron, so it is a good insulator. That is why an electric cell with rusted terminals may not work.